# Get information from several layers using forEachFeatureAtPixel method

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I want to obtain information from several layers, I am using the forEachFeatureAtPixel method, but when I get the results I only get the first result, When in the browser response, I see that the JSON it returns has more results. When I used the getFeaturesAtPixel method, I got all the results through a FOR loop. But now I don't know how to get all the results.

```
map.on("click", function (evt) {
    var result = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function (feature, layer) {
        return { feature, layer };
    });
    if (result) {
        var feature = result.feature;
        var layer = result.layer;
        if (layer === vec01) {
            contINFO.innerHTML = '<b>One name:' + feature.get('one_name') + '<b>'
        }else if (layer === vec02) {
            contINFO.innerHTML = '<b>Other name:' + feature.get('other_name') + '</b><b>Percent: ' + feature.get('percent') + '</b>'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning any truthy value in the callback will stop the detection at the first feature.  To get all features do not return a value and build up the results from each feature

```
const info1 = document.getElementById("info1");
map.on("click", function (evt) {
    var info1Count = 0;
    var contCount = 0;
    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function (feature, layer) {
        var info1HTML = '';
        var contHTML = '';
        if (layer === vec01) {
            info1HTML = JSON.stringify(
                Object.entries(feature.getProperties()).filter(function (entry) {
                return entry[0] !== "geometry";
                })
            );
            contHTML = '<b>One name: ' + feature.get('one_name') + '<b>'
        }else if (layer === vec02) {
            info1HTML = JSON.stringify(
                Object.entries(feature.getProperties()).filter(function (entry) {
                    return entry[0] !== "geometry";
                })
            );
            contHTML = '<b>Other name:' + feature.get('other_name') + '</b><b>Percent: ' + feature.get('percent') + '</b>'
        }
        if (info1HTML != '') {
          if (info1Count == 0) {
            info1.innerHTML = '';
          } else {
            info1.innerHTML += '<br>';
          }
          info1.innerHTML += info1HTML;
          info1Count ++;
        }
        if (contHTML != '') {
          if (contCount == 0) {
            contINFO.innerHTML = '';
          } else {
            contINFO.innerHTML += '<br>';
          }
          contINFO.innerHTML += contHTML ;
          contCount++;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: effectively accumulating results. How would I have to do so that each time you click, it deletes the previous result and gives the new ones? after all I'm asking for information from another point.

Comment: Hi @Mike can i use this with WMS?

Comment: @Ivan Slaughter `forEachFeatureAtPixel` only works for vector features

Comment: @user68481 Empty the result before adding the first line, add a line break for subsequent lines at the same pixel.  Or you could unconditionally reset both immediately after the click.  I've updated the answer.